# I am trying to convert my ts project to javascript and I get this error (Cannot find Module) How do I fix it

Tags: node.js, typescript

This is the full error message

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\hadiz\Desktop\FinalApp\backend\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
```

**Below is my PACKAGE.JSON**

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "firebase": "^9.12.1",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "image-downloader": "^4.3.0",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.2.0",
    "image-to-rgba-matrix": "^1.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "opencv.js": "^1.2.1",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth2": "^0.2.0",
    "remove.bg": "^1.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.3"
  }
}
```

I do think the issue might be happening from the package.json but I am not sure so i need a little help to guide me through. Might something be missing in the package.json file? Do i have to add anything or take away anything?

Comment: What do you mean with 'convert' in the title. Is that 'compile'? Which command do you run that produces the error? Does the file exist that is mentioned in the error message? Probably not, so ask yourself whether it rather should be there and how it potentially get there to solve the problem.

Comment: index.js is there. By convert I mean I want to change my index.ts file to a index.js file. The command I use to generate that error is node index.js @Harald